# Integrate Instagram in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a login with Instagram authentication using a button.  I am currently using Swift and the documentations out there are not so clear. Is it actually possible to do what I want to do? If so, how can I do it? Thanks in advance for your helps

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming related questions. I think you should seek out some tutorials to help you with your issue.

Comment: Hi, i have searched many sites and tutorials but there is no codeing or idea how I can  implement login with instagram in swift application.

Comment: If you can find one that talks you through Objective-C it should be easy enough to port it over to Swift. If you find trouble with that I would highly recommend getting to know Objective-C before diving into Swift

Comment: Did you get your solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`InstagramKit`](https://github.com/shyambhat/InstagramKit). Although it's in Objective-C, you can use bridging headers to call it from Swift code as well.